# Create shared asset files between themes

Tags: ghost-blog

When using ghost depending on the theme it will be grabbing the assets from the folder

```
ghost/content/themes/<ThemeName>/assets
```

Is there a general place to put assets ambiguous of the theme that you're using? The idea being to have a CSS file for a post referenced no matter which theme is currently being used.

My current work around is to have a file like so

```
ghost/content/general/css/file.css
```

And then linking it via

```
ln -s ghost/content/general/css/file.css ghost/content/<ThemeName>/assets/css/file.css
```

This is of course not optimal and I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not; Ghost is built similarly to WordPress, in that a theme is meant to be entirely self-contained. Of course there is nothing stopping you from directly referencing a hard-coded address in your themes (that may look outside the scope of its own folder), but this is not advised.

Also worth mentioning that you won't be able to use the `{{asset}}` helper for anything that isn't in your `/assets` folder.